# scratch/touch problem detection in android

Tags: android, canvas, touchscreen

I am looking for a solution to test the touch screen of the android device like Amazon/Flipkart etc. do.

Can I get any working reference link which does a similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ScratchView](https://github.com/sharish/ScratchView)? It seems very easy to integrate for `ImageView` and `Textview` both.

You may also check on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@anupkumarpanwar/create-google-pay-tez-like-scratch-card-65315e921068).

In addition, if you would like to create your own solution, you may place a view on top of ImageView and erase the Bitmap on touch with approach as mentioned in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297396/how-to-implement-touch-smooth-image-eraser-in-android).

Comment: I want code which tests touch screen of the phone to diagnose an issue in the touchpad.

Comment: Do you mean you need to capture the coordinate values of the screen where exactly the fault is on screen?

Comment: Yes, you can relate it with amazon phone exchange screen diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library

```
compile 'com.github.cooltechworks:ScratchView:v1.1'
```

Use the scratchable view in your `xml`

```
<com.cooltechworks.views.ScratchImageView
  android:id="@+id/sample_image"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  android:src="@drawable/img_sample2"
  />
```

Add the `listener` for your scratch view like below and check for the percentage

```
scratchImageView.setRevealListener(new ScratchImageView.IRevealListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRevealed(ScratchImageView tv) {
        // on reveal
    }

    @Override
    public void onRevealPercentChangedListener(ScratchImageView siv, float percent) {
        // if the percent is 1, then whole portion is scratched
    }
});
```

For more info https://github.com/sharish/ScratchView

Comment: I want code which tests touch screen of the phone to diagnose an issue in the touchpad.

Comment: Use the above code and set ScratchImageView to match_parent. If the whole screen is scratched i.e if the percent is 1 then all the pixels in the screen are working

Comment: This can be one of the option.